# Issues with inheritance from a parent class called "Matrix" to a child class "Square Matrix"

Tags: python, matrix, pycharm, inverse, square

My code looks to make a program which solves various things related to matrices. This is a snippit of my code which has all the relevant information to the error I am getting. Within my code, the definitions in the class Matrix (rowswap, rowmult, and rowscalaradd) are not being appropriately inherited to the child class "SquareMatrix" and give the error "Cannot find reference 'rowswap' in 'function' ". I have tried different syntax with no success, what am I doing wrong?

edit: Error appears on lines 56,59,62 of this code with the following:

Cannot find reference 'rowswap(then subsequently rowmult, and rowscalaradd respectively in lines 59 and 62)' in 'function'

Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self): 
        outstr = ""
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            outstr += 'Row %s = %s\n' % (i + 1, self.data[i])
        return outstr

    def rowswap(self, choice1, choice2):
        data = self.data
        row1 = self.data[choice1]
        row2 = self.data[choice2]
        data[choice1] = row2
        data[choice2] = row1
        return Matrix(data)

    def rowmult(self, scalar, rownumber):
        data = self.data
        for k in range(len(self.data[0])):
            data[rownumber][k] = (data[rownumber][k] * scalar)
        return Matrix(data)

    def rowscalaradd(self, modified, modifier, scalar):
        data = self.data
        for p in range(len(self.data[0])):
            data[modified][p] = data[modified][p] + scalar * data[modifier][p]
        return Matrix(data)


    class SquareMatrix(Matrix):
        def __init__(self, data):
            super().__init__(data)
            if len(self.data) != len(self.data[0]):
                raise ValueError('Not a square matrix')
        def identity(self):
           identity = self.data
           for i in range(len(self.data)):
              for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                 if i == j:
                   identity[i][j] = 1
              else:
                   identity[i][j] = 0
           return Matrix(identity)

        def inverse(self):
            data = self.data
            id = self.identity
            iters = 0
            while iters < len(data):
                for j in range(0, len(self.data[0])):
                    while self.data[iters][j] == 0:
                        self.rowswap(iters, iters + 1)
                        id.rowswap(iters, iters + 1)
                    else:
                        self.rowmult(1 / data[iters][j], iters)
                        id.rowmult(1 / data[iters][j], iters)
                    for i in range(iters + 1, len(data)):
                        self.rowscalaradd(i, iters, -1 * data[i][j])
                        id.rowscalaradd(i, iters, -1 * data[i][j])
                    iters = iters + 1
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code? Right now I'm unsure if `class SquareMatrix` is incorrectly indented inside your `Matrix` class (it shouldn't be), or if it isn't and the problem is something else. You can paste your code in, highlight all of the code, and then press the `{}` button on the editor to format your code.

Comment: If the edit that you approved is indeed correct, then you need to un-indent your `SquareMatrix` class block.

Comment: In PyCharm, the Square Matrix class is not indented compared to the Matrix class, but the program on this website would not allow it to be posted unless indented.

Comment: What is `self.identity`? It is used on line `40`, but is not set anywhere (AFAICT)? Also, it would help if you were to provide the *full* error message, including line numbers.

Comment: My apologies, I've added in the definition in as an edit along with error messages, my intent was to give precise code but I missed a definition in the process

Answer (score 1):

In `inverse`, you have a line `id = self.identity` that doesn't do what you intend. You probably want to be *calling* `self.identity`, not just referencing it. As a result, the `id` variable that you try to use later in the function is a bound method object, not a `Matrix`.

There are probably some other issues in your code. The line `identity = self.data` in the `identity` method, in addition to being confusing (since the variable has the same name as the method), also doesn't make a copy of the class's data, so when you modify it later, you're modifying `self.data` too. You should probably create the identity matrix from scratch, not from a copy of the data (only use the current matrix's size, if anything).